# select columns whose content is having a string (not names but content)

Tags: r

given this data frame (as an example, the real one has more than 100 columns):

```
df <- data.frame(column_one = 1:2,
                 column_two = 1:2,
                 column_three= 3:4,
                 column_four= 3:4)
```

I want a new data frame with columns that contained the number 4 this way:

```
column_three  column_four
3              3
4              4
```

All I can find on SO is how to select column names containing a given string but that's not my case. The column name is not my issue.

Take into account that I cannot check every column one by one on code regarding the number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this...

```
df[,sapply(df,function(x) 4 %in% x)]

  column_three column_four
1            3           3
2            4           4
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @AndrewGustar's answer, here's an equivalent solution using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
select_if(df, function(x) 4 %in% x)

#>   column_three column_four
#> 1            3           3
#> 2            4           4
```